# Trying to get a switch to loop over when the default occurs

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, prompt

Here is my code: I want my switch to loop over if someone enters a name that is not present. I'm new to JavaScript and I am learning JavaScript for work, this is something I am just making for just to practice. It works functionality wise, I am just trying to figure out a way to make it loop if it passes the default case. Thanks! For sake of not using my co-workers names I have switched all the cases to my name.

```js
String.prototype.capitalizeFirstLetter = function() {
  return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
}

var name = prompt("Please enter the name of the recipient to recieve a burn notice").toLowerCase();


switch (name) {
  case 'brent':
  case 'brent':
  case 'brent':
  case 'brent':
  case 'brent':
  case 'brent':
  case 'brent':
  case 'brent':
    alert(name.capitalizeFirstLetter() + " has revieved a burn notice, ice is located downstairs in the freezer.");
    break;
  default:
    alert("Didn't find " + name.capitalizeFirstLetter() + " please try again.");
}
```

Comment: Why do you have seven identical `brent` cases that are blank?

Comment: its called fall-through since my cases all will receive the same alert I just let it fall-through till it finds the alert. I learned about in through Codeschool.com

Answer (score 1):

Put your code in a function and call it again if you reach the default case.

```
function askForName() {
  var name = prompt("Please enter the name of the recipient to recieve a burn notice").toLowerCase();

  switch (name) {
    case 'brent':
      alert(name.capitalizeFirstLetter() + " has revieved a burn notice, ice is located downstairs in the freezer.");
      break;
    default:
      alert("Didn't find " + name.capitalizeFirstLetter() + " please try again.");
      askForName();
  }
}

// initial call to make sure the function runs
askForName();
```

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely try this!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `continue` to go to next step of a loop, if you place your code inside one.

```
for(;;) {
    var name = prompt("Please enter the name of the recipient to recieve a burn notice").toLowerCase();
    switch (name) {
        case 'brent':
            alert(name.capitalizeFirstLetter() + " has revieved a burn notice, ice is located downstairs in the freezer.");
            break;
        default:
            alert("Didn't find " + name.capitalizeFirstLetter() + " please try again.");
            continue;
    }
}
```

In the example, `continue` is redundant, but you get the idea.

Anyway, there's better ways to achieve desired functionality, if you provide more information on what you want.